# how to know which Search Bar is Active?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, iphone-4, searchbar

now I have 2 search bar at one page

the first problem is How can I make a search button always show although no text at searchbar.text?

the second problem is, I have a Table View that Will show a different list expend which search bar I choose, how can I do it well?

I can set a variable that change everytime the search bar is active. However is there a way to see which search bar is currently the active search bar?

Comment: what buttons do you need to be shown? scope bar? cancel button?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to check which view are you working with, is assigning the **`tag`** property:

```
firstSearchBar.tag = 100;
secondSearchBar.tag = 200;
```

You can easily check it:

```
if(searhBar.tag == 100) {
    // it is first search bar
} else if(searchBar.tag == 200) {
    // it is second search bar
}
```

---

Now, the second part. If you want to show cancel button, you can do it in this way:

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
```

If you want to show scope bar:

```
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
```

If you want to show search results button:

```
searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = YES;
```

---

**EDIT:** If you wish to show `Search` keyboard button even if there's no text entered, you can do it in this way:

```
UITextField *searchField = (UItextField *)[[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[searchField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
```

---

I recommend you reading [UISearchBar's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: hmm.. thank for helping me, but I want to know how to make search button show although don't have any text at searchbar.text, do you know how to make it?

Comment: Also in searchBar.tag==100 there is no variable named searchBar. Is there a pointer to whichever site has "focus"

Comment: You must change `searchBar` to your real searchBar's name. Where do you want to check which search bar is active? + Look at my edited answer for showing search button.

Comment: UITextField *searchField = (UItextField *)[[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[searchField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO; this code is not work, as we know there is a search button at keyboard, that will be show when there are text at searchbar, how can I make it always show without have any text at searchbar?